# Base64 string is received differently in the server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an image that I want to convert to base64 and send to server, to save it to database as base64 string. I use angularjs in the client side and [this](https://github.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload) to convert image to base64.

I do `console.log()` on the base64 string of the image and use an online converter to check if the string converts to image and it does. I send this string to save in the database. I want to get the stored image and display it. When I use the online converter on the same string stored in the database, I don't get the image.

I check the length of both the output(the result of the converted image which works in the online converter) string and the string stored in database and they have the same length.

I don't know why the string at the database doesn't convert to image.

The code which sends the base64 to server:

```
 $scope.SaveData = function() {
        console.log("BASE " +$scope.fileModel.base64);
        if ($scope.myform.$valid) {
          Upload.upload({
          url: $scope.ipForHttp+"addVehicles?ClassImage="+$scope.fileModel.base64+"&ClientID="+$scope.ClientID+"&filename=name", 


      })
```

This is the one that works:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHIAAABHCAIAAABUCIQ0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAwxSURBVHhe7dnLj1XFFgbw+7/AAOWh8hAUxQfy0IZgFBEZkKhBBYkhkEAgihJeRk2IMlEHJgwISMDIiMjAxMREcWACGBhJoiEOBOQloPK6v3O+pty9u/HCvdndd7C/QWXVqlWr1vpqVe063f+63qIBtLQ2gpbWRtDS2ghaWhtBS2sjaGltBC2tjaCltRG0tDaCltZG0NLaCFpaG0FLayNoa
```

The one that doesn't work:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHIAAABHCAIAAABUCIQ0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAwxSURBVHhe7dnLj1XFFgbw 7/AAOWh8hAUxQfy0IZgFBEZkKhBBYkhkEAgihJeRk2IMlEHJgwISMDIiMjAxMREcWACGBhJoiEOBOQloPK6v3O pty9u/HCvdndd7C/QWXVqlWr1vpqVe063f 63qIBtLQ2gpbWRtDS2ghaWhtBS2sjaGltBC2tjaCltRG0tDaCltZG0NLaCFpaG0FLayNoa
```

The one that doesn't work has some space

Comment: so the string is the same length, but it's different ... how different? can you show the first 20 or 30 characters **in your question**

Comment: @JaromandaX. i've posted it

Comment: Do **you** see the problem?

Comment: `+` are replaced by ` ` (space) ... you need to look at `encodeURIComponent` and the equivalent decoding

Comment: @JaromandaX. ok i will. thanks

Comment: @JaromandaX. it's working but i dont understand how i am able to display without decoding it again. i encoded using `encodeURIComponent` before sending to server. when I `console.log() ` the request I see the decoded string. i dont decode it on the server side but it is saved as the decoded string in the database